# фильтры и таги в Django Python

Tags: python, django

Всем привет! Прохожу онлайн курс и получил следующее задание:

1. Фильтр inc. Необходимо в файле создать фильтр “inc“ который принимает 2 аргумента: 1-й - число которое нужно увеличить, 2-й - на сколько нужно увеличить первое число. Пример использования фильтра “inc“:

{{ a|inc:"10" }}

2.2. Тег division. Необходимо создать тег “division“ (то есть тег для деления), который принимает 3 аргумента: 1-й - делимое, 2-й - делитель, 3-й - деление целочисленное (именованный аргумент to_int). По умолчанию необходимо сделать вещественное деление Обратите внимание, что делимое и делитель целые числа, но передается в тег в формате string.

Пример использования тега “division“:

{% division a b to_int=True %}
{% division a b %}

Сделал следущее:

```
@register.filter
def inc(a, b):
    return int(a) + int(b)

@register.simple_tag
def division(a, b, to_int=False):
    res = int(a)/int(b)
    return int(res) if to_int is True else res
```

На локальном сервере все работате и выдает как требуется, но при сдаче грейдер не принимает (и не выдает ни какой ошибки). В чем я ошибся?

Comment: Я думаю стоит уточнить какая версия python/django и django template используется в этой системе обучения. Если у вас есть различия в версии, то надо поставить именно ту версию, что на сайте обучения.

Comment: Как я понимаю Python 3.6 и выше, Django 1.11. Уже все поставил и обновил как на сайте.

Comment: И результат такой же неутешительный?

Comment: К сожалению да. Просто пишет что тесты не пройдены.

Comment: Видимо я понял в чем )) Попробуйте передать в division второй параметр "0". Уверен, вы увидите много интересного. ) + в division деление надо делать float.

Comment: БОльшое спасибо! Помогло. Вообще вылетело из головы про деление ноль. Все просто использую фильты на вводе, вот и прощелкал ))